# validate acts as taggable on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, acts-as-taggable-on

I am using [acts-as-taggable-on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) to add tagging. I have this in my model:

```
acts_as_taggable 
validates_inclusion_of :tag_list, in: %w( bug feature )
```

However, in rails console if I try:

```
i = Issue.find(1)
i.tag_list = "bug"
i.save
```

validation fails and issue tag_list is not saved. If i remove validation line then of course I am able to add tag_list.
I tried to write my custom validation too:

```
validate :tag_list_inclusion

  def tag_list_inclusion
    tag_list.each do |tag|
      return false unless %w(bug feature).include?(tag)
    end
    return true
  end
```

My custom validation does work as in it always returns true and always passes validation (even when it shouldn't).
only validation which works as it should is:

```
validates_presence_of :tag_list
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods

My custom validator was:

```
  def tag_list_inclusion
    tag_list.each do |tag|
      errors.add(tag,"is not valid") unless %w(bug feature).include?(tag)
    end
  end
```